# Unexpected EOF when linking Arduino project in Eclipse on OS X

Tags: eclipse, macos, linker, arduino, avr

I have been trying to link Arduino and Eclipse, and I feel like I'm close.

Where should I start looking for this?

Similar errors have been caused by extra/incomplete quote blocks (according to google searches). I have already dug through my AVR linker settings looking for quotes, but haven't had much luck.

Am I looking in the right place?

Which files should I check?

I have already looked in the file I have written myself (in this case, the basic Arduino blink program).

```
**** Build of configuration Release for project C64_Arduino1 ****

make all 
Building target: C64_Arduino1.elf
Invoking: AVR C++ Linker
avr-gcc --cref -s -Os -o"C64_Arduino1.elf"  ./C64_Arduino1.o ./CDC.o ./HID.o 
./HardwareSerial.o ./Print.o ./Stream.o ./Tone.o ./USBCore.o ./WInterrupts.o ./WMath.o ./WString.o ./malloc.o ./wiring.o ./wiring_analog.o ./wiring_digital.o ./wiring_pulse.o 
./wiring_shift.o   -l"Arduino_Mega_2560_or_Mega_ADK" -lm -L/Users/Chet/Desktop/Chet's Shit/Side Projects/Programming/C64_Arduino1/Release -L"/Users/Chet/Desktop/Chet's Shit/Side 
Projects/Programming/C64_Arduino1" -mmcu=atmega2560
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [C64_Arduino1.elf] Error 2

**** Build Finished ****
```

**EDIT:**

I have commented out all of my code (including #include's) except the main (which is empty) and I still get the error. I have set up my IDE as specified [Here](http://robots.dacloughb.com/project-1/setting-up-the-arduino-eclipse-environment-on-mac-os-x-lion/) and also [Here](http://horrorcoding.altervista.org/arduino-development-with-eclipse-a-step-by-step-tutorial-to-the-basic-setup/). Still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the actual error message:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I can see that the problem is most likely due to some kind of Makefile syntax error.

When you write a make rule such like:

```
foo:
    touch foo
```

What make does, it first checkes whether file called `foo` exists already, if not, then it runs command `/bin/sh -c 'touch foo'`. So the line where we said `touch foo` should have valid shell script syntax.

Looking at the command that you ended up running:

```
avr-gcc --cref -s -Os -o"C64_Arduino1.elf"  ./C64_Arduino1.o ./CDC.o ./HID.o 
./HardwareSerial.o ./Print.o ./Stream.o ./Tone.o ./USBCore.o ./WInterrupts.o ./WMath.o ./WString.o ./malloc.o ./wiring.o ./wiring_analog.o ./wiring_digital.o ./wiring_pulse.o 
./wiring_shift.o   -l"Arduino_Mega_2560_or_Mega_ADK" -lm -L/Users/Chet/Desktop/Chet's Shit/Side Projects/Programming/C64_Arduino1/Release -L"/Users/Chet/Desktop/Chet's Shit/Side 
Projects/Programming/C64_Arduino1" -mmcu=atmega2560
```

I can see that the issue is with the `'` character in some of the directory paths. You should either escape it (as in `"/Users/Chet/Desktop/Chet\'s Shit"`) or, as a quick work-around symlink or move the directory.

As a general methodology tip, you should first check whether everything works in CLI, and then move on to teaching Eclipse what commands it should run.

Also, I would consider using the tool called *[ino](http://inotool.org/)* instead of make, it might just work with minimum configuration. I have had some experience replacing Arduino IDE with just a Makefile, but it gets hairy when you need to use different boards and perhaps several connected at the same time. Give *ino* a try, it looks quite promising.

Comment: Ah, I was looking for " instead of '. Thank you for the information and the recommendation for ino. I appreciate your time.